# How can I make Google Chrome remember a password I have deleted from saved passwords

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

A while ago I removed some saved passwords from different Google accounts in Chrome. Afterwards I logged in to the different Google accounts again and with 4 out of 5 accounts, Chrome asked to save the password, which it did. However, when I log into the fifth account, Chrome does not ask to save the password.
It is not included in the exceptions list, nor is it saved anywhere else.
I've already tried:

- Disabling and re-enabling Save passwords
- The trick with disabling Javascript
- Resetting Chrome profile

However, none of these seemed to help. What can I do more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) It could help if you erase Cache and restart browser.
Then make sure you have logged into the appropriate account.
Take a look at the stored passwords. Make sure the site is not listed there.
Execute in the address field:
chrome://settings/passwords

2.) Another way is to use the very popular Chrome Extension "LastPass" which will make storing passwords easier. It can be used ACROSS different accounts, since you'll have to log into it, to enable storing and remembering passwords.

3.) https://passwords.google.com - This is the centralized online personal storage everyone has at Google. See what records are there for this account. Sometimes the "Local" account and the online account storages need some time to synchronize. Above all passwords there is a preference - "Auto Sign-In", make sure it is enabled.
How, and when, synchronization works can be checked with a command in the address field: chrome://sync-internals
Check under "Identity" what is the current "Username", and is it synchronized.

Comment: None of the solutions seemed to fix it, so I took your advice and installed the LastPass extension. Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted a saved password and now Chrome will not ask to save the password do this. Do a Google search for the web site do not use your bookmark link. Now click on the link in the search and get to the web site that way. When I did this Chrome asked for and save the password.