# I deleted password from chrome://settings/passwords now I want to put it back but Chrome will not ask

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, cache, cookies, autosave

I deleted a password from `chrome://settings/passwords`. I now want to put it back but Chrome will not ask me to save it. (I deleted it because I saved the wrong password.) Now I know the password and I want Chrome to remember it.

I have tried:

- finding the deleted site on the "never saved" section and it is not there.
- changing the auto sign-in and offer to save password settings
- erasing the cache and the history
- erasing the passwords and reinstalling them
- https://passwords.google.com and the "declined sites and apps", but my site is not listed.
- [How can I make Google Chrome remember a password I have deleted from saved passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/974231/how-can-i-make-google-chrome-remember-a-password-i-have-deleted-from-saved-passw)

All efforts and more have not worked. Chrome will not ask me to save the details for one particular site. Previously it would remember the password and not the username. Which was strange, but I was able to look up the user name each time I wanted to log on. Now I have to write down the password on paper, which is not what I want to do. Please help me re-attach the password to saved passwords.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I force Google Chrome to remember passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

> There is no direct way to add a password to Chrome without using third party software. If a website no longer asks you to save the password after selecting the "No" option, you can reset this choice in the settings.

Read more from this answer: [How can I manually add a password to Chrome password manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/1519402/how-can-i-manually-add-a-password-to-chrome-password-manager)